# Site name is not vertically centered for beta sites with longer names

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, beta-sites

[image]

***Arrrgghhhhhh!!!***

This only affects beta sites with longer names, such as [Programming Puzzles & Code Golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com), [Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com), and [Music: Practice & Theory](http://music.stackexchange.com).

I'm using Chromium 40.0.2214.111 on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Reproduced in Chrome on Windows. Failed to reproduce in FF and IE 11.

Comment: Reproduced on firefox 36.0.1 on 64bit Linux.

Comment: Reproduced in Safari on an iPad (iOS 7).

Comment: Ditto terdon but in Windows.

Comment: |||||||||||\|||

Comment: This seems to be fixed for main, but not for meta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stéphane and Jin pushed styling fixes for this. Should be fixed (both for main and meta) in the next build.